# How to set the precision on str(numpy.float64)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

i need to write a couple of numpy floats to a csv-file which has additional string content. therefore i dont use savetxt etc. with numpy.set_printoptions() i can only define the print behaviour, but not the str() behaviour. i know that i miss something and it cant be that hard, but i dont find a reasonable answer on the interwebs. maybe someone can point me in the right direction. heres some example code:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: foo = np.array([1.22334])

In [3]: foo
Out[3]: array([ 1.22334])

In [4]: foo[0]
Out[4]: 1.2233400000000001

In [5]: str(foo[0])
Out[5]: '1.22334'

In [6]: np.set_printoptions(precision=3)

In [7]: foo
Out[7]: array([ 1.223])

In [8]: foo[0]
Out[8]: 1.2233400000000001

In [9]: str(foo[0])
Out[9]: '1.22334'
```

How do i convert np.float to a nicely formatted string, which i can feed to file.write()?

kind regards,

fookatchu

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just use standard string formatting:

```
>>> x = 1.2345678
>>> '%.2f' % x
'1.23'
```

Comment: i get the point, thanks. thought it whould be this easy... the other answers work also. thanks to all!

Answer (score 12):

You could use normal String formating, see:
http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec

Example:

```
print '{:.2f}'.format(0.1234)  # '0.12'
print '{:.2e}'.format(0.1234)  # '1.23e-01'
```

Comment: the code you posted didn't work. but the link is very helpful! the right syntax whould be: '{0:f}'.format(a[1]).

Answer (score 7):

Numpy 1.14 and later have [`format_float_positional`](http://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html#numpy.format_float_positional) and [`format_float_scientific`](http://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_scientific.html#numpy.format_float_scientific) functions to format a floating-point scalar as a decimal string in positional or scientific notation, with control over rounding, trimming and padding. These functions offer much more control to the formatting than conventional Python string formatters.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.float64('1.2345678')
print(np.format_float_positional(x))  # 1.2345678
print(np.format_float_positional(x, precision=3))  # 1.235
print(np.format_float_positional(np.float16(x)))  # 1.234
print(np.format_float_positional(np.float16(x), unique=False, precision=8))  # 1.23437500

y = x / 1e8
print(np.format_float_scientific(y))  # 1.2345678e-08
print(np.format_float_scientific(y, precision=3, exp_digits=1))  # 1.235e-8
```

etc.

---

These advanced formatters are based on the Dragon4 algorithm; see Ryan Juckett's [**Printing Floating-Point Numbers**](http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/printing-floating-point-numbers/) to read more on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `str(foo[0])`, use `"%.3f" % foo[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do:

```
precision = 2
str(np.round(foo[0], precision))
```

It had some advantages for me over the ('%.2f' % x) when I needed to do string a str(np.log(0.0)) which is neatly treated to "-inf" by numpy so you don't have to bother here.